# Finding neighbouring cells in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function that will look at the coordinates of two cells and return a boolean response if they are adjacent or not.

I am thinking that because of this:

```
data Coord = Coord {xCoord, yCoord :: Integer}
deriving (Ord, Eq, Show, Read)
```

My function needs to take two integers and then (this is the part i need help with) check that they are neighbours.  Everything I have written will break, as it also allows for two non-neighbouring cells to return a true.

Please Help. =]

Comment: I guess you meant to say `My function needs to take two _coordinates_` , right?

Comment: Yeah, it needs to look at two coordinates.  But are they being expressed as Integers, right?

Comment: The code in your question suggests they are being expressed as `Coord`s, which have `Integer`s for the x and y values. (Also, you should post the code you have already (edit it into the question), it allows people to help you more effectively :) )

Comment: Do you consider diagonally adjacent cells such as `(0, 0)` and `(1, 1)` adjacent, or only cells which share an edge?

Answer (score 1):

I guess two coordinates are adjacent in your sense if they are not equal, and the distance in X *and* Y direction between them is at most one? If so, you could use

```
adjacent :: Coord -> Coord -> Bool
adjacent p q | p == q = False
adjacent (Coord x1 y1) (Coord x2 y2) = abs (x1 - x2) <= 1 && abs (y1 - y2) <= 1
```

Comment: Another common interpretation of adjacent is that one of `x` and `y` is equal and the other differs by 1. That would lead to `abs (x1-x2) + abs (y1-y2) == 1`, making the equality check unnecessary.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, true. You should make that separate answer, I guess. I don't know about the actual interpretation of the OP, so your way may be more appropriate than what I suggest.

Comment: Not worth a separate answer. Add it to yours and let the OP pick which meets his/her criteria.